# How to create a pause in javascript/jquery code that follows a call to asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

How can I call an asynchronous function and then create a pause in the code that follows the call to the function so that I may be (almost) sure that the asynchronos function has finished?
I don't want to put the code that follows the call inside a function and then delay it to achieve this, just pause the code as it is for a few seconds.

Here is what I mean:

```
<script>
   asynchronousFunction(); // start running immediatly

   waitFor10Seconds(); // only the following code should wait while the async 
                       // function is running in the background

   rest of the code; // this code will start running after 10 seconds have passed 
                     // since the async function has been called     
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried it and had many complications that I've asked about here and no one was able to find their source. Can you please say how to do it without a callback?

Comment: No, you want a callback. Do it right, and figure out the error, rather than doing it wrong. Your way will work "some times" and is absolutely the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @meagar, of course doing it right is the way to go, but I've been trying to find the problem for almost three weeks now and no can help me with that (many have tried) and I'm out of options.

Answer (score 4):

It's called `setTimeout`

```
asyncThing();
setTimeout(function() {
    // do stuff
}, 10000);
```

Ideally though the async operation should allow you to pass a callback so you turn it into

```
asyncThing(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: the problem is all my code lies inside a submit() function.
Wont the code that follows the call be executed only after the form has been submitted? Please don't offer `event.preventDefault()` and then call `submit()`. I've tried it and there's a problem in my case no one can locate.

Comment: @Ash obvious solution is to just change your submit button to click buttons and to suppress enter key submission. Dont submit the form. Try `$("form").serialize()`

Comment: are you saying I should delete the `submit()` function and write a `click()` function instead or do you mean I should change the button definition? How do I suppress enter key submissions?

Comment: @Ash event.preventdeault on keyup/press for e.which === 13

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you should really use a callback. It's easy with jQuery:

```
$.get("page.php", "key1=value1", function(data) {
    // Code in here will be executed when response has been received
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

You can of course use $.post() if you'd rather POST the data.

Answer (score 1):

Aldo a callback is better practice, this what you asked for

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 10000);
```

Comment: @jerone, which code should be called in that callback? the asynchronous function or the following code. I want to delay the following code, not the async function.

Comment: @jerone, OK. Now what if all the code (including the call to the async function) is inside a submit() function? If I put the following code in the setTimeOut function I believe the form will be submitted before the following code will run. I want the code to run before the form is submitted. Please don't offer `event.preventDefault()` and then call `submit()`. I've tried it and there's a problem in my case no one can locate.

Comment: Canceling a form submit does work with `preventDefault`, or you can try `return false;`. Are you sure submitting (e.g. `document.forms[0].submit()`) does work? This is a different problem and without code hard to solve...

Comment: @jerone, my case is really weird but after calling `preventDefault()` or `return false` I have no way to submit again. I've tried many advices I recieved here. I have no choice but using the original submit. But only after all the code has finished. Is there no way of pausing a code without putting it inside a function?

Comment: @Ash. The submit button probably have events on it. I can't think of a way that both executes a code after a specified timeout and still execute the previous events. Sorry.